# Marriage visitor visa refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, weddings

I have been living in Egypt with my partner (married in Egyptian court, not at the Embassy) for the past 6 years. We applied to come to the UK on a marriage visitor visa. Our intentions were to get married, visit my family (I am English) and both return to Egypt after 3 months.

However we were refused as they thought it would be against all probability that we would leave, even after we had reason to return and provided evidence (my partner had a job, home and family to attend to) and in any case we preferred to live in Egypt. We did not have the right to appeal.

What further evidence can we supply to prove we would not intend to stay in the UK?

Comment: Please upload your refusal letter (blocking out personal info). We need to know why they didn't accept the evidence already submitted

Comment: This reads like you are already married, so a marriage visit visa wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Are you married to your partner or not? One sentence says you are married in an Egyptian court, but then you say you want to get married in the UK? A [Marriage Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa) is for people who want to get married.

Comment: She may have an Islamic marriage which appears to not be recognized by the UK.

Comment: @mkennedy: Do you have a reference for that? Egypt has legally recognized religious courts with jurisdiction over family matters, and generally the UK recognizes foreign marriages if they're legally valid in the country they were performed in, no matter whether a religious ceremony was perfomed. E.g. https://www.myerson.co.uk/recognition-foreign-religious-marriages/

Comment: Islamic marriages (that are conducted by designated officials) are recognized by the UK; so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @DJClayworth: From my reading of the question, I suspect the OP wants to conduct a second wedding celebration/ceremony. From a legal point of view, that is irrelevant (thus the marriage visa refusal), but in my experience, it is definitely common among "international couples" to think of themselves as having married twice. This may have confused the OP.

Answer (score 2):

> I have been living in Egypt with my partner (married in Egyptian
>   court, not at the Embassy) for the past 6 years. We applied to come to
>   the UK on a marriage visitor visa. Our intentions were to get married,
>   visit my family (I am English) and both return to Egypt after 3
>   months.

As you are already legally married in Egypt, you don't qualify for a marriage visitor visa - which is for a partner who needs to travel to the UK for the purpose of getting married.

Your marriage in Egypt is legally valid in the UK.

If you and your partner would like to visit the UK, I would recommend:

1. Getting your marriage certificate certified by the appropriate authorities, then translated (if not already in English) and have the translation certified as well.
2. If you are a UK citizen you only need to apply for a regular visitor visa for your spouse. This should be a lot simpler process.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning there is nothing stopping the OP having a 'marriage like ceremony' in the UK, so that friends and family can celebrate with the couple, it just won't count as a wedding for UK legal purposes.

Comment: True, and more importantly would not qualify the person for a marriage visitor visa.